# Add Panel control to form from class object

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm still a bit green on C# so please forgive me if I'm asking the question in the wrong way.

I'm writing a windows Forms program. I have a form with a Tab control on it. Inside the Tab control on one of the tabs is a FlowlayoutPanel control
I have a class with various properties. This class represents the data on a contacts card, i.e. Name Address, Phone etc. and is designed to look like a Panel control. Here is some code:

```
public class clsContactCard
{
#region Fields (8) 

    private Color _backColour;
    private BorderStyle _borderStyle;
    private List<string> _detailLines = new List<string>();
    private Color _foreColour;
    private Size _size;
    private string _subTitle;
    private string _title;

#endregion Fields 

#region Constructors (1) 

    public clsContactCard()
    {}

#endregion Constructors 

#region Properties (8) 

    public Color BackColour
    {
        get { return _backColour; }
        set { _backColour = value; }
    }

    public BorderStyle BorderStyle
    {
        get { return _borderStyle; }
        set { _borderStyle = value; }
    }

    public List<string> DetailLines
    {
        get { return _detailLines; }
        set { _detailLines = value; }
    }

    public Color ForeColour
    {
        get { return _foreColour; }
        set { _foreColour = value; }
    }

    public Size Size
    {
        get { return _size; }
        set { _size = value; }
    }

    public string SubTitle
    {
        get { return _subTitle; }
        set { _subTitle = value; }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; }
    }

#endregion Properties 

    public Panel CreateCard()
    {
        // New Contact Card  
        Point labelLoc = new Point(18, 11);             //Location for a label
        Size labelSize = new Size(218, 16);             //default label size

        Panel pnl = new Panel();                        //Instantiate a new Panel
        pnl.BackColor = _backColour;                    //Set the new panel's properties
        pnl.BorderStyle = _borderStyle;
        pnl.Size = _size;
        pnl.Visible = true;

        //Title
        Label l = new Label();                          //Create new label object
        l.Name = "uxTitle";                             //Give it a name
        l.Text = _title;                                //Assign it data from properties
        l.Size = labelSize;                             //set its size & font
        l.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",10,FontStyle.Bold);
        l.Location = labelLoc;                          //set its location
        labelLoc.Y += labelSize.Height;                 //update next labels location
        pnl.Controls.Add(l);                            //add label to panel controls

        //Type
        //Label l = new Label();
        l.Name = "uxSubTitle";
        l.Text = _subTitle;
        l.Size = new Size(215, 15);
        l.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",7,FontStyle.Regular);
        l.Location = new Point(21, 27);
        labelLoc.Y += labelSize.Height + 5;

        //Detail lines
        int lineCount = 0;
        bool firstPhone = true;

        foreach (string line in _detailLines)
        {
            if (SAPSCommon.Instance.IsNumeric(line.Trim()) && firstPhone)
            {
                firstPhone = false;
                labelLoc.Y += 5;
            }
            lineCount += 1;
            //Label l = new Label();
            l.Name = "uxLine" + lineCount;
            l.Text = line;
            l.Size = labelSize;
            l.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8,FontStyle.Regular);
            l.Location = labelLoc;
            labelLoc.Y += labelSize.Height + 5;
        }
        return pnl;
    }
}
```

The idea is to show the card object in a FlowLayoutPanel control akin to MS Outlook contacts list. I have the code to populate the object properties, but when I try to add the card object (panel) to the FlowlayoutPanel control the compiler complains about the types:

> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'SAPS.clsContactCard' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

The code is a s follows:

```
foreach (clsContacts contact in _pensioner.Contacts)
{
    clsContactCard card = new clsContactCard();
    if (contact.OtherNames != "")
    {
        card.Title = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", contact.Givname, contact.OtherNames,
                                   contact.Surname);
    }
    else
    {
        card.Title = string.Format("{0} {1}", contact.Givname, contact.Surname);
    }
    card.SubTitle = contact.ContactTypeDescription;
    card.DetailLines.Add(contact.Addr1);
    string addr2 = contact.Addr2;
    if (addr2.Length >= 0) 
        card.DetailLines.Add(addr2);
    card.DetailLines.Add(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", contact.Suburb, contact.State, contact.PCode).Trim());
    string country = contact.Country;
    if (country.Length >= 0)
        card.DetailLines.Add(country);
    foreach(clsPhoneNumbers phone in contact.PhoneNumbers)
    {
        card.DetailLines.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", phone.PhoneNumber, phone.PhoneType));
    }
    foreach(clsEmailAddresses email in contact.EmailAddresses)
    {
        card.DetailLines.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", email.EmailAddress, email.EmailType));
    }
    card.CreateCard();

    uxContactDetsFlp.Controls.Add(card);
}
```

Can anyone shed a light on what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? I thought the panel control could be added to the flowlayout panel.

Comment: Well you need to add a control to the panel what it seems is your adding your class to the control, As per your layout you can have a usercontrol with say textbox to fill in the Particulars of your class which would show up in your panel

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Please only post the problematic section. It's a hassle to wade through the entire code.

Comment: Apologies for unnecessary code. I wasn't sure how much was needed to illustrate my problem.
Also thanks for heads up about salutations.

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Ummm...That's what I thought I was doing, creating a Panel object with Label objects that contain the data in the appropriate place on the panel. Then adding that panel to the flowlayoutpanel to be shown. Originally I had 1 panel invisible on the flp which I cloned then populated the label controls, problem is sometimes some labels are blank and shouldn't show, hence my new class/object approach. I guess I'm not understanding the grass roots concept of object, class and control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add anything else that is not a control to container control like FlowLayoutPanel. You should instead add the panel itself rather than the card object. Do it like this:

```
Panel pnl = card.CreateCard();
pnl.Tag = card; //optional
uxContactDetsFlp.Controls.Add(pnl);
```

Additionally you can `Tag` the panel with the card object if you have to retrieve the card object later on.

Comment: downvote? How? I don't think I did...Still trying to understand exactly how this site works.

Comment: @WalterKiess you will learn more with time spent here. You should not forget to accept the answer that helped you by clicking on the green tick at the top left of that answer. That's a good practice followed here on stackoverflow to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work since you are not inheriting your class from a Control. You can only add classes inherited from Control to control collections such as in Panel.Controls etc.

```
public class clsContactCard : Control
```

When so you need to override the OnPaint event handler to render the content to your custom panel.

From [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skcysbt2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> If you want to create a completely custom control to use on a Windows
>   Form, you should inherit from the Control class.

You could also inherit the Panel control and override its OnPaint to make life a little easier.

Update - Here are some resources to start with:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0k2e6x.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b818z6z6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx 
 
[http://bytes.com/../c-sharp/...creating-custom-controls-movable-resizable-container-control](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/insights/911860-creating-custom-controls-movable-resizable-container-control) 
http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/firstnetctrl.htm

Comment: This is an innovative idea, but I dont recommend it. Is clsContactCard a Control as Dog is a Mammal? No. So better dont inherit. This could be a bad design choice.

Comment: This sounds like it might work, but it's a bit complex for my limited knowledge. I will try it by inheriting from the Panel control. Not sure how I will handle the Paint override though.

Comment: @WalterKiess I updated my answer with a couple of resources that can help you start off. In essence what you do is to render the content to your control in the OnPaint. You can use basic GDI+ functions such as DrawString etc. Check out the links for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone offering suggestions. Most were over the top of my head but I did have a closer look at them. In the end I followed nawfal's advice. I reread my code and found I wasn't assigning the panel object produced by the `CreateCard` method to anything. I wanted to use the Panel object created by the card object to populate the flowlayoutpanel not the card object itself (silly me). So the only change I really needed to make was this small code segment at the end of the `PopulateContactDetails` method:

> ```
>             //Create a new panel ...
>             Panel cd = card.CreateCard();
>             //... and show on screen
>             uxContactDetsFlp.Controls.Add(cd);
> ```